# Setting default Enum while parsing using Gson

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I have a use case wherein while parsing JSON to POJO using GSON library, I need to alter the value of enum based on some condition.
The conditions are like

```
enum Status{
 A,B,C,D,DEFAULT
}
```

And the JSON from the server be like **"status":"A" or "B"** etc.
Suppose a new status is added on the server side like **"status":"G"**. 
In case of the above response, I want to set the status to a **DEFAULT** enum type.
What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two options.

1. Make `Status` be `String`
2. Use `Gson` custom deserializer like this(Kotlin example).

   ```
   class StatusDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Status> {
       override fun deserialize(
           json: JsonElement,
           typeOfT: Type,
          context: JsonDeserializationContext
       ): Status {
           val jsonObject = json.asJsonObject
           return when(jsonObject.get("status").asString) {
               "A", "B", "C", "D" -> context.deserialize<Status>(jsonObject, Status::class.java)
               else -> Status.DEFAULT
           }
       }
   }

   val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Status::class.java, StatusDeserializer()).create()
   ```

Comment: @Choim....thanks ...actually we were thinking of the first approach !!...but the second approach is left out due to previous design issues.... looking for any other alternative way to approach with a better design...